# App on Facebook side to post status update

Tags: android, facebook

I created an android app which successfully posts a status update on the user's FB wall.

But to achieve this I had to create an app on facebook side. Is there a way to do this without facebook side app?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I had to create an app on facebook side" ?

Comment: Facebook side app is *must !*

Comment: I mean if I can skip bullet point 5 of the getting started guide at developer site of Facebook:
"Create a new Facebook app, get its ID and associate your Android key hash with it". See:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is (as Ming Li and Muhammad Babar pointed out): You must create a facebook side app to get your android app to post status update.